# From Jenkins, how do I get a list of the currently running jobs in JSON?

Tags: jenkins

I can find out just about everything about my Jenkins server via the Remote API, but not the list of currently running jobs.

This,

```
http://my-jenkins/computer/api/json
```

or

```
http://my-jenkins/computer/(master)/api/json
```

Would seem like the most logical choices, but they say nothing (other than the count of jobs) about which jobs are actually running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/309848/how-can-i-check-the-build-status-of-a-jenkins-build-from-the-command-line

Comment: That question is about checking a single build result, I'm looking to inspect what jobs are currently running.   Different things in this case.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. I think I stumbled across a solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have a view defined using [View Job Filters Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters) that filters just currently running jobs, then you can use `/api/json` on the view page to see just the jobs that are running. I also have one for aborted, unstable, etc.

**UPDATE**

Select *Edit View* → ***Job Filters*** → <kbd>***Add Job Filter*   ▼**</kbd> → ***Build Statuses Filter***
   *Build Statuses*:   ☑ *Currently Building*
   *Match Type*:   *Exclude Unmatched - ...*

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to fetch the build #'s of the running jobs? I created a view as you described, the json contained the job names but no build numbers.

Answer (score 66):

There is often confusion between **jobs** and **builds** in Jenkins, especially since jobs are often referred to as 'build jobs'.

- **Jobs** (or 'build jobs' or 'projects') contain configuration that describes what to run and how to run it.
- **Builds** are executions of a job. A build contains information about the start and end time, the status, logging, etc.

See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project for more information.

If you want the **jobs** that are currently building (i.e. have one or more running **builds**), the fastest way is to use the REST API with XPath to filter on colors that end with `_anime`, like this:

```
http://jenkins.example.com/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,url,color]&xpath=/hudson/job[ends-with(color/text(),%22_anime%22)]&wrapper=jobs
```

will give you something like:

```xml
<jobs>
  <job>
    <name>PRE_DB</name>
    <url>http://jenkins.example.com/job/my_first_job/</url>
    <color>blue_anime</color>
  </job>
  <job>
    <name>SDD_Seller_Dashboard</name>
    <url>http://jenkins.example.com/job/my_second_job/</url>
    <color>blue_anime</color>
  </job>
</jobs>
```

Jenkins uses the `color` field to indicate the status of the job, where the `_anime` suffix indicates that the job is currently building.

Unfortunately, this won't give you any information on the actual running **build**. Multiple instances of the job maybe running at the same time, and the running build is not always the last one started.

If you want to list all the running **builds**, you can also use the REST API to get a fast answer, like this:

```
http://jenkins.example.com/computer/api/xml?tree=computer[executors[currentExecutable[url]],oneOffExecutors[currentExecutable[url]]]&xpath=//url&wrapper=builds
```

Will give you something like:

```xml
<builds>
  <url>http://jenkins.example.com/job/my_first_job/1412/</url>
  <url>http://jenkins.example.com/job/my_first_job/1414/</url>
  <url>http://jenkins.example.com/job/my_second_job/13126/</url>
</builds>
```

Here you see a list off all the currently running builds. You will need to parse the URL to separate the job name from the build number. Notice how `my_first_job` has two builds that are currently running.

Comment: This does not seem work anymore, on my case it does return all jobs, not builds.

Comment: If you need all of the currently running builds (and their build number) this seems to work on the current version of Jenkins (2.103): http://jenkins.example.com/computer/api/xml?depth=2&tree=computer[executors[currentExecutable[building,url]],oneOffExecutors[currentExecutable[building,url]]]&xpath=//currentExecutable[building=%27true%27]/url&wrapper=builds

Answer (score 13):

Bit of a hack but I think you can infer what jobs are currently running by looking at the color key in the job objects when you do a `GET` at `/jenkins/api/json?pretty=true`. If the 'ball' icon for a given job in Jenkins is animated, we know it's running.

Have a look at the array of job objects in the JSON response:

```
{
 ...
  "jobs" : [
    {
      "name" : "Test Job 1",
      "url" : "http://localhost:8000/jenkins/job/Test%20Job%201/",
      "color" : "blue"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Test Job 2",
      "url" : "http://localhost:8000/jenkins/job/Test%20Job%202/",
      "color" : "blue_anime"
    }
  ...
}
```

In this case `"color" : "blue_anime"` indicates that the job is currently running, and `"color" : "blue"` indicates that the job is not running.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, although the balls dont always tell the correct story.   In particular if a job is disabled while running (which natuarlly is my case) - the ball is color "disabled" even though the job is currently running.

Comment: The URL is http://<domain and port>/api/json?pretty=true in my 2.164 version

Comment: Also, I have folders and it shows just the folders. You have to issue another request using the URL in folder json with /api/json following. So it would take a bunch of tree following to find all the running jobs (and, of course, they would be changing as you made the calls if you hadn't gone into shutdown mode).

Answer (score 10):

Marshal the output and filter for "building: true" from the following call to json api on a job with tree to filter out the extraneous stuff (hope this helps):

```
http://jenkins.<myCompany>.com/job/<myJob>/api/json?pretty=true&depth=2&tree=builds[builtOn,changeSet,duration,timestamp,id,building,actions[causes[userId]]]
```

will give you something like:

```
{
  "builds" : [
{
  "actions" : [
    {

    },
    {
      "causes" : [
        {
          "userId" : "cheeseinvert"
        }
      ]
    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {

    },
    {

    }
  ],
  "building" : true,
  "duration" : 0,
  "id" : "2013-05-07_13-20-49",
  "timestamp" : 1367958049745,
  "builtOn" : "serverA",
  "changeSet" : {

  }
}, ...
```

Comment: Is there any way to display results that have only `building: true` and that ignore `building: false`?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with the jenkins tree api, using an endpoint like this:

```
http://<host>/api/json?tree=jobs[name,lastBuild[building,timestamp]]
```

You can see what attributes from `lastBuild` you can use if you access `<job-endpoint>/lastBuild/api/json`.

Comment: If Folders are used, they appear to be "jobs nested in jobs" so a more complicated tree is needed, e.g.

    ```/api/json?tree=jobs[name,url,color,lastBuild[building,timestamp],jobs[name,url,color,lastBuild[building,timestamp],jobs[name,url,color,lastBuild[building,timestamp],jobs[name,url,color,lastBuild[building,timestamp]]]]]&pretty=true```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where some pipeline builds get stuck in the building state after I restart jenkins (piepline jobs are supposed to be durable and resume but most of the time they get stuck indefinitely).

These builds do not use an executor so the only way to find them is to open every job.

All of the other answers seem to work when the project is considered building, i.e.: the last build is building. But they ignore past builds still building.

The following query works for me and gives me all the currently running builds, i.e.: they do not have a result.

http://localhost:8080/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,builds[fullDisplayName,id,number,timestamp,duration,result]]&xpath=/hudson/job/build[count(result)=0]&wrapper=builds

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked me properly. I copied and modified code form python-jenkins. Since Master node name changed , it was giving exception. Did'nt want to rely on plugin.

```
def get_running_builds():
builds = []
        nodes = server.get_nodes()
        for node in nodes:
            # the name returned is not the name to lookup when
            # dealing with master :/
            if node['name'] == 'Built-In Node':
                continue
            if node['name'] == 'master':
                node_name = '(master)'
            else:
                node_name = node['name']
            try:
                info = server.get_node_info(node_name, depth=2)
            except server.JenkinsException as e:
                # Jenkins may 500 on depth >0. If the node info comes back
                # at depth 0 treat it as a node not running any jobs.
                if ('[500]' in str(e) and
                        server.get_node_info(node_name, depth=0)):
                    continue
                else:
                    raise
            for executor in info['executors']:
                executable = executor['currentExecutable']
                if executable and 'number' in executable:
                    #print(f'{executable}')
                    executor_number = executor['number']
                    build_number = executable['number']
                    url = executable['url']
                    m = re.search(r'/job/([^/]+)/.*', urlparse(url).path)
                    job_name = m.group(1)
                    builds.append({'name': executable['fullDisplayName'],
                                   'number': build_number,
                                   'url': url,
                                   'node': node_name,
                                   'executor': executor_number,
                                   'timestamp': executable['timestamp']})
        
  
       
        return builds
```

timestamp gives time in millisecs.