# How to get the list of builds in progress in jenkins using java?

Tags: java, jenkins, hudson

I'm using this URL to get a response of several builds related statuses such as latest successful, list of builds,latest completed,latest stable etc ..

```
http://JenkinsServer:8080/jenkins/job/jenkins_job/api/json
```

i was able to get the list of jobs as well but im unable to get the builds currently in progress, for instance if builds X Y and Z are currently running and i sent the request, i need a response of these builds in progress, i tryed several suggested URLs from Jenkins website but nothing gave me this specific request

Comment: Try this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843874/from-jenkins-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-currently-running-jobs-in-json

Answer (score 1):

Check for the color property.
In my case is "color" : "red_anime" when  a job is running.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the build is in progress is signaled by the building property in the json response.