# Get a list of currently running jenkins builds with their parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm writing a pipeline job using groovy. I need to get the info about running builds of the same job, with the build's parameters and their ids, so I can later filter it by parameters

I found these questions how to achieve that

[From Jenkins, how do I get a list of the currently running jobs in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843874/from-jenkins-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-currently-running-jobs-in-json)

[How do I Efficiently list **All** currently running jobs on Jenkins using Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988884/how-do-i-efficiently-list-all-currently-running-jobs-on-jenkins-using-groovy)

and the proposed solution do return the information about the jobs, but they return too many results (not only active jobs) and have other problems

For example `http://jenkins.example.com/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,url,color]&xpath=/hudson/job[ends-with(color/text(),%22_anime%22)]&wrapper=jobs` doesn't return any info about builds

The closest guess so far was `https://jenkins.example.com/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,status,id,result,builds[number,actions[parameters[name,value]]]]&xpath=/hudson/job[name="job_name"]&wrapper=job_names&pretty=true` but it returns lost of just `action` items and doesn't indicate which builds are active

Any help to achieve what I want is appreciated. The preferred output is JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below API:

`https://jenkins_domain/job/test_job/api/json?tree=builds[id,building,actions[parameters[name,value]]]`

But you can't really filter the results, because XPath is not supported in JSON API

Comment: I'm having difficulty finding documentation about `tree=builds` and the available properties on a build. Does anyone know where to find that information in the Jenkins documentation?